# Proof (intuition) that indicator variable $Y$ is measurable w.r.t. to $\sigma$-algebra $G$

Tags: measure-theory

I have the indicator variable $Y(w)$ which takes on the value $1$ if $w \in A$ and $0$ else. I want to prove that $Y$ is measurable with respect to some $\sigma$-algebra $G$. I know that $A \in G$.

I found this solution, where $B$ is a Borel subset of the real line:

$Y^{-1}(B) = A$ if $1 \in B$, $0 \notin B$

$Y^{-1}(B) = A^{c}$ if $0 \in B$, $1 \notin B$

$Y^{-1}(B) = \Omega$ if $0,1 \in B$

$Y^{-1}(B) = \emptyset$ if $0,1 \notin B$

Since $A$, $A^{c}$, $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ are all in $G$, $Y$ is measurable w.r.t. $G$.

Could anyone explain me the intuition of this solution? (I do understand why $A$, $A^{c}$, $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ are all in $G$, but I do not understand the rest.)

Comment: Why the downvote? What is wrong with the question?

Comment: Before invoking intuition and the like, what would *you* do to prove the result?

Comment: I have just started looking into this, so I am not able to come up with my own proof. I'd really appreciate any help in understanding this proof.

Comment: Yeah, and what about putting the *definitions* on the table? You know, they could prove useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Y$ is a map from $(\Omega,\mathcal{G})$ to $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. By definition of a measurable function, we have to show that for any $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $Y^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{G}$.

I recall that $Y^{-1}(B):=\{\omega\in\Omega,\, Y(\omega)\in B\}$.

Now $Y$ is an indicator function, so the only values it takes are $0$ and $1$. Thus, if $0\not\in B$ and $1\not\in B$, we have $\{\omega\in\Omega,\, Y(\omega)\in B\}=\emptyset$.

For the same reason, if $0\in B$ and $1\in B$, then $\{\omega\in\Omega,\, Y(\omega)\in B\}=\Omega$, because every $\omega$ is mapped to $0$ or $1$, hence $Y(\omega)$ belongs to $B.

Now if$ 1\in B$ and $0\not\in B$. Then clearly $\forall\omega\in A$, $Y(\omega)\in B$, which shows that $A\subset Y^{-1}(B)$. Conversely, let $\omega\in Y^{-1}(B)$. Then $Y(\omega)\in B$ and $Y(\omega)\in\{0,1\}$. As $0\not\in\Omega$, $Y(\omega) = 1$, which implies that $\omega\in A$. Hence $Y^{-1}(B)\subset A$ and the equality. The proof for the last case is identical.